# Sorting a list with Objects and A primitive String

Tags: collections, comparator

I am trying to sort a list as given below.

```
List dg = new ArrayList();
dg.add(new Dog("one"));
dg.add(new Dog("two"));
dg.add(new Dog("three"));
dg.add(new Dog("four"));
dg.add(new String("Ankit"));
```

I have tried to implement comparable for Dog class below (not sure if it is useful here)

```
//Dog class below//
class Dog implements Comparable<Dog>{
String name;

public Dog(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {

    return name;
}
 public int compareTo(Dog d){

     return this.getName().compareTo(d.getName());
 }
```

The issue is however I write the comparator as given below I get ClassCastException. How to solve this?

---

```
class StringComparator implements Comparator {
  public int compare(Object d, Object s) {
    String p=((Dog)d).getName();
     return (p.compareTo(s.toString()));
    }
}
```

---

```
//usage of the above comparator

Arrays.sort(odog,sc);
```

Comment: You should add your programming language as a tag so it's easier to find for others.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is:

See that to a list you are mixing String object with Dog objects using `dg.add(new String("Ankit"));` Do you really need string object.

Then you try to sort it using your comparator and your comparator blindly type cast values to Dog object. So when it encounters your String object it tries to type cast it to String object which is not possible (due to Dog not a subclass of String) and hence you get ClassCastException.

I would remove String object from Dog list to resolve the issue.

Comment: But that is the desired behavior...I want all dog names and a string to be compared..